# Image preview before posting

Tags: javascript, jquery

The upload button in the picture below allows the user to choose photo. Image should immediately display and Next button is used to post the request.

[image]

I am doing this in following way:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action='{{URL::route('postImage')}}' runat="server">    
<div class="form-group">
        <label class='col-md-4 control-label'>Profile Picture</label>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
                <img src='/images/default.jpg' id='image' class="img-responsive img-circle img-thumbnail img_profile pull-left"> 
                <input type="file" name='profile_picture' id="file_ID" class='hidden' >
               <a href='#' class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.getElementById('file_ID').click(); return false;"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-camera'></span> Upload Photo</a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

My JS code is as follows:

```
 function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#image').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#file_ID").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

The Next button is not working. It is simple button with type submit. What might be wrong with it? I would highly appreciate your help.

Comment: We can't see all the relevant parts of your app: the code you posted is not an "MVCE" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Specifically, you don't include your "Next" button in the HTML, so we can't help you troubleshoot what could be causing the issue. Also "not working" is an unhelpful description of your problem. What behavior are you seeing, and what behavior do you expect to see?

Comment: Thank you Palpatim for your response.. Images and other files of higher size need enctype= multipart/form-data and it was the problem...